# Flutter firestore limit the number of write operations a user is allowed

Tags: flutter

I'd like to know if there is a way to limit the number of write operations a user can make to a collection using flutter. For example if the user has already posted 5 documents, they should not be able to create any more until they delete some of the existing documents

Answer (score 0):

You can store how many times the user has written to the database with a `SharedPreference` and then manage the UI in case it can or cannot load on `Firestore`.

Then every time a document is uploaded by that user, check with a cloud function that it has not exceeded the upload limit.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in future who might want to achieve something similar. I used the get() route to get the number of documents the user currently has in the firestore collection, then used if statement to implement my logic

```
Future checkuploads()async{
    //check firestore for the number of  posts the user currently has active
   return FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('collecttionname')
       .doc(userid)
       .collection("othercollection")
   .get()
       .then((value) {
     var count = 0;
     count = value.docs.length;

if(count>=3){
//do something

}else{
//your upload function

}

//the call the above function where you need it


}
```